# R - Looping with while always results in missing value where TRUE/FALSE is expected

Tags: r, loops, data.table

**EDIT:** I implemented offered solutions so far, and the code looks way cleaner now. This was the key to finally finding my error. It was a logical condition that I didn't check within the while loop. It could happen that the iterator would exceed the number of elements in the vector and thus pass a "NA" to the while condition! Thx

I also changed the solution to use vector assignments to store the results and then recombine after the for loop, as vector indexing seems to be way faster than data.table indexing and value assignment within the loop.

---

Pls let me apologize first for any errors and lack of information for troubleshooting my problem as this is my first post so far. I have already read that this can happen accidentally whenever ther is an error in a computation and the value of a condition results in an error, such as
`if (TRUE & sqrt(-1))`

It's been days and I am still receiving this error. It really gives me a headache, as the inherent logic behind such code is actually pretty straigth forward and I still can't properly formalize it. It goes like following: Compare for each unique bond ID contained in a vector of size N (loop through with i), the static value of its corresponding maturity to 7 periods' end date for distinct set of rules (loop through with k) to determine which periods with unique rules the respective issue falls into, and then determine by looping through all the periods' size thresholds (loop through by l) to find if a particular issue has violted these minimium size requirements. If a violation is determined, I can assign the date of the violation. If `(l == k)`, I can reckon that for all periods that the issue's maturity falls into, have also successfully looped through the corresponding size requirements checks and as such hasn't violated any rules. I then assign the result of the conditional checks as corresponding binary values in a new data.table column as well as the violation date. So far, I really cant determine what is casusing this error.

My data looks like following. I have a pretty large data.table containing bond issue identifiers and various other column variables that describe those issues. It was imported as initially with the `read_dta()` function and then transformed to a data.table with `setDT()`.

I extract 3 columns out of this data.table, using

```
issue_IDs.vec     <- as.numeric(issues.dt[[2]])
maturity.vec      <- as.Date(issues.dt[[8]], "%Y-%m-%d")
offerings_atm.vec <- as.numeric(issues.dt[[33]])
```

Next, I transform eligibility criteria of an index as following.

```
# (1) Creating size requirement end periods (valid thru) ----
size_req_per_1 <- as.Date("1992-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
size_req_per_2 <- as.Date("1994-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
size_req_per_3 <- as.Date("1999-07-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
size_req_per_4 <- as.Date("2003-10-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
size_req_per_5 <- as.Date("2004-07-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
size_req_per_6 <- as.Date("2017-02-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
size_req_per_7 <- as.Date("2021-02-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
size_req_val_per.vec <- c(size_req_per_1, size_req_per_2, size_req_per_3, size_req_per_4,
                          size_req_per_5, size_req_per_6, size_req_per_7)

# (2) Create a size requirement threshold per rules' validity period ----
size_req_thresh_1   <-  25000
size_req_thresh_2   <-  50000
size_req_thresh_3   <- 100000
size_req_thresh_4   <- 150000
size_req_thresh_5   <- 200000
size_req_thresh_6   <- 250000
size_req_thresh_7   <- 300000
size_req_thresh.vec <- c(size_req_thresh_1, size_req_thresh_2, size_req_thresh_3,
                         size_req_thresh_4, size_req_thresh_5, size_req_thresh_6,
                         size_req_thresh_7)
```

Next, I do write a loop to perform conditional checks to find for each issue ID stored in the issues_ID.vec if they violate the index eligibility criterium of the minimim issance size during their maturity. I do this by passing the value of iterator variable i as a position value to the issues_ID.vec.

```
# (3) Looping through a set of conditional check to find out if and if so when a particular issue violated the size requirement ---
   
# Iterator variables ----
# Length of issues.dt
j <- issues.dt[, .N]

# Main iterator looping through all entries of isssues.dt extracted as vector
i <- 1

# Looping through vector elements of issue rules (vec. 1: validity periods)
k <- 1

# Looping through vector elements of issue rules (vec. 2: size thresholds) 
l <- 1



# Loop

for (i in 1:j) {
  id            <- issue_IDs.vec[i]
  maturity      <- maturity.vec[i]
  offering_atm  <- issue_IDs.vec[i]
  
  k <- 1
  maturity_comp <- size_req_val_per.vec[k]
  
  while (maturity >= maturity_comp) {
    if (k < 7) {
      k <- k + 1
      maturity_comp <- size_req_val_per.vec[k]
    } else {
      break
    }
  }
  
  l <- 1
  offering_size_comp <- size_req_thresh.vec[l]
  
  for (l in 1:k) {
    if (offering_atm >= offering_size_comp) {
      offering_size_comp <- size_req_thresh.vec[l]
      next
    } else {}
  }
  
  if (l == k) {
    issues.dt[ISSUE_ID == id,
              `:=`(SIZE_REQ_VIOLATION = 0,
                   SIZE_REQ_VIOLATION_DATE = NA)]
  } else {
    issues.dt[ISSUE_ID == id,
              `:=`(SIZE_REQ_VIOLATION = 1,
                   SIZE_REQ_VIOLATION_DATE = size_req_val_per.vec[l])]
  }
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Whenever I try running the code in a simplified version, such as

```
k <- 1
for (1 in 1:7) {
  print(maturity >= maturity_comp)
  k <- k + 1
  maturity_comp <- format(as.Date(size_req_val_per.vec[k]), "%Y-%m-%d")
}
```

the code runs smooth and always results in the printed evaluations TRUE or FALSE, depending which ID I initially to create the corresponding static maturity of the particular bond issue. As this stage, I already exhasuted my troubleshooting skills.

I'd appreciate any input from you guys, and if you need any additional information, explanations etc. just let me know.

Comment: It looks weird to me that you have `l <- l + 1` inside your `for (l in 1:k)` loop. The `for()` means that `l` will iterate as `1, 2, 3, 4, ... k`. If you want to jump to the next iteration, use `next`.

Comment: In the main `i` loop, is it on purpose that you have the definition of `maturity_comp <- format(as.Date(size_req_val_per.vec[k]), "%Y-%m-%d")` using `k` **before** you reset `k  <- 1`? That seems like it could be an issue.

Comment: To answer your first comment. You're absolutely right! I replaced the ```l <- l + 1``` with ```next``` in the line after the variable assignment.

Comment: And relating to your second comment: As I define ```k <- 1``` outside the main for loop, I can use ```k``` to determine the corresponding maturity. I ```reset k to 1``` at the end of the loop, so the comparison of a bond's _static maturity date_ starts with the _first date stored in the size_req_val_per.vec_ every i^th iteration of the for loop. Is that the correct way to do it?

And I need this to be a separate iterator variable as i goes up to the total length of the extracted vectors, as opposed to k which is supposed to only go from 1 to 7 (7 periods) every i^th iteration.

Comment: Well, you set `k <- 1` *before* the loop, so that is run before the first `i` iteration. I don't see any reset of `k <- 1` at the end of the loop. So that means when you get to `i = 2` iteration, `k` still has the final value from the `i = 1` iteration when you define `maturity_comp`, and **then** you reset `k <-1`. Seems like the `k <- 1` inside the loop should come before that, unless you want the `maturity_comp` "remembered" from the previous iteration.

Comment: I couldn't edit my previous answer, as I was drafting my answer! You are absolutely right!

Could I just move the initialization of ```k <- 1``` up a few lines ahead of the _Initialize first vector element to compare maturity to_ line?

That would be equivalent to moving this line ```k <- 1``` to the second last line right before the main ```for``` loop closing right? F.ex. ```i <- i + 1``` then ```k <- 1``` and then the closing bracket for the main for loop ```}```

If equivalent, what would be the preferred solution?

Comment: Right, that's what I'm suggesting. Don't know if that's your only problem, but it stuck out to me when I skimmed your code. The error was with `maturity_comp` or `maturity`, so the first thing I did was look at their definitions.

Comment: One last comment - why do you `format` all your dates as character strings? Seems like it would be a lot easier to leave them as `Date` class... If you really need them that way, maybe make yourself a utility function like `ymd <- function(x) format(as.Date(x), "%Y-%m-%d")`. But in your current code, `maturity_vec` is a `character` class object, but practically every time you use it you convert it from character to Date then back to character. Makes things hard to read and inefficient. Even if you keep it as `character`, don't convert it back and forth.

Comment: Acutally, your way of reasoning in your troubleshooting is great. I'll keep that in mind. Adressed this and made the corresponding changes. I'll look at your next comment now and try to understand how I can adress that as well.

So annoying, that looking at it all by yourself I never seemed to notice these "obvious" flaws....

Thanks for your help so far. Appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks Gregor! You definitely helped me to streamline my code. Unfortunately, I still see the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer lies in Gregor's comment.  The way you are formatting your dates converts them to character variables.  Here's a quick example:

```
Exmpl<-as.Date("08-25-2020", "%m-%d-%Y")
class(Exmpl)

[1] "Date"

##Not your preferred format, but it is a Date variable##
Exmpl
"2020-08-25"

##Formatting changes it to a character
Exmpl2<-format(as.Date(Exmpl), "%m-%d-%Y")
class(Exmpl2)
[1] "character"
```

When you call them in the `while()` function, R is trying make a comparison to decided if the condition (i.e., maturity is greater than or equal to maturity comp) is TRUE or FALSE (logical variables).  Because you have character variables, R cannot make this comparison.

I think your code will work if you don't format the dates, but simply read them in and leave them in the YYYY-mm-dd format.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I saw that this caused a problem, and actually there was no reason for the conversion. 

I edited my original code to now extract the Date column ```maturity``` directly as date and remove the ```format(..., "%Y-%m-%d")```. All other data of type ```Date```is defined as such at assignment, f.ex. ```size_req_val_per.vec```. I still do get this error though

Comment: Note: as far as I am concerned, I do 3 conditional checks. 

(1) ```while (maturity >= maturity_comp)```
Both objects are of type Date

(2) ```if (offering_atm >= offering_size_comp)```
Both objects are of type Numeric

(3) ```if (l  ==  k)```
Both variables (iterators) are of type Numeric

Both 2 + 3 shouldn't cause any issue, but the code breaks already at conditional check 1 in the while loop.

Comment: You might need to start running print statements to where in the loop things are breaking.  I would add `print(class(maturity)` and `print(class(maturity_comp))` before the `while()` function and rerun the loop.  If you do, please post the output here

Comment: I' ll do that in just a bit. I start suspecting sth here as well! After commenting the while loop out, the code does not break, even though the semantic then doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It results in ```[1] "Date"
[1] "Date"
[1] "Date"
[1] "Date"
[1] "Date"
[1] "Date"
Error in while (maturity >= maturity_comp) { : 
  Missing value, whereTRUE/FALSE is neccessary```

Comment: I checked whether the loop acutally did write the results of the conditional checks to the ```issue.dt``` data.table as defined in the condition check nr. (3) ```if (l  ==  k)```

I run the following command ```issues.dt[is.na(SIZE_REQ_VIOLATION), .N]``` and get [1] 47697. As the number of rows of the issues.dt data.table is the same as the length of the three extracted colums as vectors is 47699 and the loop posts 6 times ````[1] "Date"``` means that for the first 3 elements it runs successful and then breaks. I'll look into the issue further